# GraphQL Nexus - adding custom scalar type

Tags: graphql, scalar

GraphQL Nexus is fairly new and the documentation appears to be lacking. In addition the examples are lacking as well. From the example and from the doc I am trying to add my own NON-GraphQL scalar type. I created my own scalar following the example in the documentation however when I try to call it in an objecttype I get the read underline. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
t.field("data", {type: "JSON"});
```

That works perfectly fine with TypeScript. 
And I wish they had better examples and documentation. Their examples only cover the most trivial use cases. I'm getting very heavily into GraphQL, Prisma, Nexus and related tool for a huge data set. So I'm literally hitting every limitation and lack of documentation that exists.

But alas we can pool our knowledge here.

Comment: I get this error:

Missing type JSON, did you forget to import a type to the root query?

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue what I did was:
1. once you create your own scalar type such as:

```
 #json.ts **FILE NAME MATTERS**
 export const JSONScalar = scalarType({
 name: "JSON",
 asNexusMethod: "json",
 description: "JSON scalar type",
 ...})
```

2. Once I called the new type in a separate object I had to add this above my field for it to compile, you may not have too:

```
  //@ts-ignore
    t.topjson("data");
```

3. In my make schema I added the scalar code first:

```
  const schema = makeSchema({
    types: [JSONScalar, MyObject, BlahObject],
```

The name of the file is very important I think that is how the schema is generated and looks for the new type. I also think you have to be sure to compile that code first in the makeSchema however I did not try to switch around the order as I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to make my own scalar type work.

This may have been self explanatory for more seasoned Nexus developers however I am a novice so these steps escaped me.

Happy coding!